# Remove container padding when resizing browser screen

Tags: html, css

I have a div "wrapper" inside of a div "container". The wrapper is 90%width and the container is 100% width. The body has a min-with of 800px and a margin of 10px. When I resize my browser (making it smaller) I want the margin to go away so that all is left is the wrapper with 0 margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('body').css('margin','0px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind("resize", function() {
    $("body").css("margin","0px");
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. This is what I have:  <blockquote><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/resize.js"></script></blockquote>   Then I have the code that you wrote in the file resize.js